# Sumif nonadjacent cells in a row

Tags: excel, row, multiple-columns, cells, sumifs

I want to calculate the sum of some cells from a row based on the value of the cell that is in front of it.
See the image bellow for more details:

***Sumif nonadjacent cells in a row:***

[image]

Note that this is a simplistic version of my actual case. In my case I have hundreds of rows and tens of columns. It wouldn't be feasible to transpose the row into 2 columns, and I couldn't use nested ifs since you can use only 7.
Is there any solution to this case?
Any other recommendation would be most appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please next time you ask a question, put the formulas and data as text in the question so we can copy and paste your formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT in this method:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(H5:V15="A"),(I5:W15))
```

Notice that the two ranges are offset by one column.

[image]

Or you can also use SUMIF with offset columns:

```
=SUMIF(H5:V15,"A",I5:W15)
```

The only rule between the two formulas is that the ranges be the same size.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!
I have used SUMPRODUCT before, but now I see that I wasn't using it correctly. Selecting the ranges correctly is very important.